# Customize expander - UWP App

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have an UWP app (published in Windows/Microsoft Store), and I want add an Expander, based on the UWP Community Toolkit Sample App, but wanted to customize it.
I have this code:

```
<controlsToolkit:Expander x:Name="Expander1"
                          Margin="0,0,0,10" 
                          Header="Details"
                          IsExpanded="False"
                          ExpandDirection="Down"
                          RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                          RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                          Foreground="Gray"
                          BorderThickness="2">
    <controlsToolkit:Expander.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.4"/>
    </controlsToolkit:Expander.BorderBrush>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Details Example"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</controlsToolkit:Expander>
```

I want the expander button to have a gray border, but I do not know why that border does not appear:

[image]

And when I click on my expander, I want the background to be grayed out instead of this blue, but I do not know how I do it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like the Expander honors BorderBrush or BorderThicknes styles. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1583) and [a PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/pull/1585) to fix this.

The control will respect the Background property and will apply it to the Header and the Content. However, the ToggleButton used for the Header does have a style that applies a system color (the accent color) for when it is Checked (aka expanded).

You can modify the header color by adding a resource to the expander

```
<controls:Expander.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Red"/>
</controls:Expander.Resources>
```

Or you can restyle the control to change the ToggleButton style to not change the background color when it is checked

Comment: I can not put a border on my expander button like I have in my code?

Comment: The latest dev build of the toolkit does allow for this now. You can either pull in the dev build (risky) or just wrap the Expander with a Border directly.

Comment: But border dont appear in my app, and I am using this code: ... `BorderThickness="2">
    <controlsToolkit:Expander.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.4"/>
    </controlsToolkit:Expander.BorderBrush>`

Comment: Wrap the Expander with a Border means to wrap the Expander with a Border control. ```<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Gray"><Expander/></Border>```

Comment: But I want the border with `Opacity="0.4"`

Comment: So make it with opacity 0.4

Comment: You can accomplish that the same as you did when trying to set the brush for the expander
<Border><Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" Opacity="0.4"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
<Expander/>
</Border>

Comment: I do like this approach very much since it doesn't require overriding complete styles. However, in my version of the Expander the resource being used is now called "SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush". So my code looks like this:
`<Custom:Expander.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="{ThemeResource ExpanderBackgroundColor}"/>
</Custom:Expander.Resources>
`

I also used a ThemeResource to make sure it's still okay when the user switches themes from Light to Dark.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the expander control template, add it to your page / app resources and tweak it.
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Expander/Expander.xaml

I'll take a look at the issue you are facing soon.

Comment: I've been copying the code to the UWP Community Toolkit Sample App and based on that! And I just edited the code and customized it my way, which is what I want!
I want to put a gray border around it and I can not!

Comment: @shawn has filed an issue for this - https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1583. could you by any chance create a repro ?